# Unable to access my cPanel?

Tags: dns, cpanel, web-hosting

Recently I bought a domain from bigrock which is www.printfalgos.net. But when I am accessing the cpanel from my ubuntu 14 it is showing:

`503 Service Unavailable
Failed to connect to server printfalgos.net`

But when I open cpanel from my mobile it is working fine.

Comment: This question does not have any long-term value for readers, I suggest it is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

it's should be an DNS problem...
try to change your dns to a public one, like level3 (4.2.2.4 8.8.8.8)